# TopTrailing alignment is not working when trying to position the vStack inside of zStack

Tags: swiftui, vertical-alignment

I am new to SwiftUI. I am trying to create a view like heart card but not being able to place the vStack of heart and letter at the top-right(topTrailing) corner of the rectangle.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
            .fill(.white)
            .stroke(.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
            .shadow(color: Color(.black).opacity(0.3), radius: 5)
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("A")
                .font(.callout)
            
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
        }.frame(alignment: .topTrailing)
    }
}
```

here is what I get as output.
[image]

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a border to the `VStack`, you can see how the content of the `VStack` completely fills its frame:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    // as before
}
.frame(alignment: .topTrailing)
.border(.orange)
```

[image: Screenshot]

What this `.frame` modifier is doing is to align the content of the `VStack` within a frame of the same size. But since the content already fills the frame, it makes no difference.

With these changes it can be made to work:

- Move the `.frame` modifier that sets the size of the card *from* the `RoundedRectangle` *to* the `ZStack` that contains all the content.
- Add `maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity` to the `.frame` modifier being set on the `VStack`, so that the frame expands to use all of the space available.
- You might like to add a bit of padding to the `VStack` too.

```swift
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
        // as before, but without .frame

    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        // as before
    }
    .padding(8) // <- ADDED
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing) // <- maxWidth and maxHeight added
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 150) // <- moved from RoundedRectangle
```

So what this does is to fix the size of the `ZStack` to the card size. A `RoundedRectangle` (like any `Shape`) is greedy, so it expands to fill the same space. The `.frame` modifier on the `VStack` now causes it to expand to the size of the `ZStack` and the `alignment` parameter aligns the content as you intended it to.

[image: Screenshow] or with a border on the `VStack`: [image]

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I have one question though- what is the difference between frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing) and frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)

Comment: @Natasha Pleased to have been able to help, thanks for accepting the answer. About the two variants of `.frame`: when you set `width` or `height` then you are setting the exact size. That is why the second variant is actually invalid, because you can't use a non-finite value for `width` or `height` (if you try it, you will see an error in the console). But `.infinity` can be used for `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` and it causes the view to expand as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell ZStack to align its sub-views, you have to use  ZStack alignment property, something like:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: topLeading) {
  ...
}
```

You could try this alternative way:

```swift
var body: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
        .fill(.white)
        .stroke(.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0))
        .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
        .shadow(color: Color(.black).opacity(0.3), radius: 5)
        .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("A")
                    .font(.callout)
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
            }
            .padding(5)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("A")
                    .font(.callout)
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
            }
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1, height: -1)) //<- make the view up side down
            .padding(5)
        }
}
```

Output:

[image]